# Search lists for keyword matches with an arbitrary string list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have an arbitrary list of strings that I would like to query my sharepoint lists with.  If any of the strings appear in a list item 'title' I would like to return that result.  Right now, the only way I know how to do this is by making a bunch of `<OR>` nodes in my caml query, but is there a way to make it so I do not have to dynamically generate an OR node for every one of my strings in the list?  something similar to this:

```
<Contains>
<FieldRef Name="Title" />
<Value type="text"> Value1</Value> (OR)
<Value type="text"> Value2</Value> (OR)
<Value type="text"> Value3</Value>
</Contains>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to SharePoint is your best option. In SharePoint 2010 you do not need to worry about the underlying CAML by using [LINQ to SharePoint](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/02/19/sp-2010-getting-started-with-linq-to-sharepoint-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx). Your LINQ query would be as simple as this:

```
 var results =  from r in datacontext.List 
    where r.title.Contains(Value1) OR r.title.Contains(Value2)
```

I had to write code to generate dynamic OR and AND nodes in CAML to do the same thing in SharePoint 2007/WSS3. Using [U2U CAML builder dll/library](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/CamlQueryBuilder_DLL.aspx) made the job easier though.